# Why do "tweeted" events appear in post revisions?

Tags: discussion, revisions-list, twitter

I thought revisions (the page that appears when you click on the "edited..." link on a post) were for displaying events related to the modifications of a post (changing title/content/tags/...).

But I saw this recently:

[image]

Why does the Twitter event appear here? I would understand seeing it in the timeline of the post (and it is, indeed, shown there), but what purpose does it serve to have it in the revisions? This isn't a revision: the post hasn't been modified in any way.

Comment: If those twitter accounts would pull in serious crowds that history would be the place to find out why your site got swamped.

Comment: @Helmar The operative word being "if"? (I dunno, maybe those work for some sites I'm not on.)

Comment: I suspect it's for historical reasons; the new timeline is fairly recent, but the Twitter notification was put in quite a while ago, and presumably stuck in a convenient place.

Comment: @Helmar But wouldn't it be the role of the timeline page, rather than the revision?

Comment: @dim yeah I guess it could be suppressed in the edit history.

Comment: Now if only "appeared in Hot Network Questions" was noted in the timeline...

Comment: @Jeffrey Well, it is, under an event marked "tweeted"... Er... actually, part of the history group. So, you're right, it's in the timeline *because* it's part of the history, it seems. It should probably be an event on its own, then.